# Fitting bivariate copula by looping through columns

Tags: r

I'm trying to fit a copula model to bivariate data, `u2` which is a vector and each column of `u1` which is a data frame with 2 variables. Here is my code

```
library(copula)
normal.cop <- normalCopula(c(0.6,0.3,0.6),dim=3,dispstr="un")
n=100
set.seed(2)
Dataset=rcopula(normal.cop, n)
u <- apply(Dataset, 2, rank) / (n + 1)
u1=u[,2:3]
u2=u[,1]

for(m in 1:ncol(u1)) 
{ 
  LIST[[m]]<-fitCopula(normal.cop1, cbind(u2,m), method="mpl") 
  LIST[[m]]=coef(m)
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work and I'm getting this error:

> Error in eigen(mat) : infinite or missing values in 'x'

In addition: Warning message:

> In cor(x, method = "kendall") : the standard deviation is zero.

I'll appreciate your help